# OpenSSL get key length of all certs

Tags: tls, certificates, openssl

I am trying to ensure that all certificates in a chain for a host have a key length of 2048 bits. Using openssl s_client, only the key length for that host's cert is given, is there a simple way to list the key length for all from the command-line, or is it necessary to download all the certs and check manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a public-accessible server, use https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html. Otherwise, see below for a script.

I am not aware of a `s_client` option that lists the key size for all certificates in a chain. You could use the `-showcerts` option to get all certificates provided by the server and check each of the provided certificates and assume that certificates in your trust store do not use small keys.

Note that some servers might be misconfigured to supply certificates in the chain that are not used (and incorrect). I remember seeing a site that would connect fine in Firefox, but fail in Java. It turned out that an old, expired CA was included in the chain along with the other certificates. Firefox would in this case just ignore that certificate as it found a valid certificate chain. `openssl s_client -showcerts` prints all certificates, even the ones that is unused (I have just verified that by appending a fake 1024-bit certificate to the chain).

The following script parses `openssl s_client -showcerts` output:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
# Match all certificates
/^-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----$/ { in_cert=1; }
in_cert { cert = cert $0 "\n"; }
/^-----END CERTIFICATE-----$/ { in_cert = 0; }
!in_cert && cert {
    infocmd="openssl x509 -text -noout | grep -E 'Public-Key:|Subject:'";
    print cert | infocmd;
    close(infocmd);
    cert="";
}
# Print the verification result
/Verify return code/
```

Then use the above `bits.awk` with:

```
echo | openssl s_client -CApath /etc/ssl/certs \
    -connect example.com:443 -showcerts 2>/dev/null | ./bits.awk
```

The output looks like:

```
        Subject: CN=example.com
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
        Subject: O=Trusted Certs Ltd., CN=Trusted CA
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
        Subject: CN=Insecure
                Public-Key: (1024 bit)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

The first two lines are actually used for the chain verification, the last one isn't, but the script does not know that.